# Form Data not getting in Laravel 5.7 that post from Angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel, angular2-forms

I am using `Angular 7` and `Laravel 5.7`. I need to post data from Angular to Laravel.

Here is My `Angular 7` code to post data to laravel api :

```
const target = event.target;
        const name = target.querySelector('#name').value;
        const phone = target.querySelector('#phone').value;
        const file = target.querySelector('#file').files[0];
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' +  Cookie.get('token'),
                'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2)
            })
        };
       const input = new FormData();
        input.append('name', name);
        input.append('phone', phone);
        input.append('file', file);


        this.http.post(this.globvar.apipath + 'api/dpost/update/' + this.slug, input, httpOptions ).subscribe(
            data => {
console.log(data);

            },
            error => {}
        );
```

and here is my Laravel 5.7 Controller Code :

```
static public function updatecarspa($slug, Request $request)
    {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($request->input('name'));
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;

       // $slug = $request->input('name');

        return response()->json(['data'=>$slug], 200);
    }
```

There is no Error print from laravel its print blank `<pre></pre>`;

I am new to angular and I am not getting any data from angular to laravel. Please help me.

Comment: any errors? and does your angular app make actually request to the server?

Comment: there is no error, its print blank

Comment: and request has been made by angular app? you can check in browser network tab

Comment: yes request is give `200 ok` status and response is `<pre></pre>`

Comment: Try `request()->get("name")` instead of `$request`.

Comment: Tryed request()->get("name") but print blank

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but your `formData` is body, and you should get body of request, and in it there will be name  $request->getBody()->name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got Conclusion

In Laravel 5.7 with API  you can post only JSON data. So in my angular I post `Content-type` data with `multipart/form-data` so with angular `Content-type` need to change  `application/json`

so with angular I change :

```
 const input = {'name' : name, 'phone': phone, 'address' : address, 'pincode' : pincode, 'website' : website, image : this.is_uploded ? this.imagedata : ''};


    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' +  Cookie.get('mmraccesstokenhope'),
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2) + ';',
        })
    };

        this.http.post(this.globvar.apipath + 'api/dpost/update/' + this.slug, input, httpOptions ).subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => {
                this.Main.loading = false;
                alert('update Success');
                this.router.navigate(['/list/dpost']);

            },
            error => {}
        );
```

also for `Image` file you need to send base64 data url Sting to API server and save image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your Angular code.

Try below.

```
$inputs = Request::json()->all();
print_r($inputs['name']);
```